# onEndReached FlatList React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

i currently have a FlatList in my React Native project that renders the posts from nodejs backend. I have applied the pagination to my backend and it is working when i am testing it on postman. My problem is when i test my app on a simulator when i reach the end of the page 0, page 1 does not load.

Here is my FlatList:

```
 <FlatList
      data={posts} // to have all the data
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <PostCard
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
        />
      )}
       onEndReached={onScrollHandler}
       onEndThreshold={0}
    />

 const { data: posts, error, loading, request: loadPosts } = useApi(
postsApi.getPosts
  );

 useEffect(() => {
loadPosts();
  }, []);

  const[page,setPage]=useState(0);
  const[profiles,setProfiles]=useState([]);

  const fetchRecords=(page)=>{
  const newRecords = []
  for(var i = page * 10, il = i + 10; i < il && i < posts.length; i++){
  newRecords.push(posts[i]);
  }
  setProfiles(...profiles, ...newRecords)
  }

 const onScrollHandler =()=>{
 setPage(page+1);
 fetchRecords(page)
 }
```

Here is my nodeJS backend:

```
  router.get("/",
  async (req, res) => {
  const getPagination = (page, size) => {
const limit = size ? +size : 10;
const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;

 return { limit, offset };
 };

const { page, size } = req.query;
 const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);

 const posts = await Post.findAll({
 limit,offset,
```

Here my route is /posts which i declared in my index.js in my backend.

Before applying pagination in my backend, when i used to do console.log(posts) in frontend i used to get all my posts but after i applied pagination when i do console.log(posts) i only get the posts for the first page.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to concatenate newly fetched records with the records that you already have, if that is the case, then you are supposed to do it like below:

```
setProfiles([...profiles, ...newRecords])
```

example:

```js
let str1 = [1,2,3,4]
let str2 = [5,6,7,7]
// you dont want that
console.log(...str1, ...str2)

// but this, it will create a new array, 
// having elements of both str1 and str2 which is what should be 
console.log([...str1, ...str2])
```

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
  );

  const onEndReached = () => {
    let newPosts = Array.from(
      { length: 4 },
      () => 'New Item Added ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    );
    console.log(newPosts)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPosts([...posts, ...newPosts]);
    }, 1000);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={posts}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        keyExtractor={(posts) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card style={styles.card}>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{item}</Text>
          </Card>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  card: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Expo Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/flatlist_example)

Screenshow:

[image]

Comment: That is true, but still when i reach the bottom of page the new page does not get rendered

Comment: do one thing, try console logging ```newRecords```.
I think there is something wrong with your for a loop.

Comment: when i do console.log(newRecords) i get this Array []

Comment: exactly, you are not getting an empty list of ```newRecords``` hence nothing is getting added to your previous profiles and the data remains the same.

Comment: in postsApi.getPosts function i was using this const getPosts = () => client.get('/posts') but now when i changed it to this const getPosts = () => client.get(`'/posts?page=${page}'`); i keep getting error cannot find variable page

Comment: In your ```router.get("/",async (req, res) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(req));
  const getPagination = (page, size) => {...```

and see what it is returning

Comment: i get this error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Comment: when i just do console.log(req) i get a get my entire request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225015/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-kd12345).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put this in useEffect.

```
  useEffect(()=>{ apiCall()},[page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect if your onScrollHandler function is called whenever you reached at the end of the flat list.

Also please wrap your flat list inside SafeAreaView and give SafeAreaView style of flex : 1

```
<SafeAreaView>
<FlatList/>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Wrap your FlatList inside SafeAreaView tag instead of view and inspect if on reaching at end your function is triggered or not

Comment: yes i added a console.log('end reached') and it is getting called whenever i reach the bottom of screen

Comment: I think issue is here in this line of code 
const onScrollHandler =()=>{
 setPage(page+1);
 fetchRecords(page)
 }

state does not gets updated when fetchRecords functions is called. Use declarative approach here .

`React.useEffect(()=>{
fetchRecords(page)
},[page])` 

and inside your function just update the state 

`const onScrollHandler =()=>{
 setPage(page+1);
 }`